# "addDependency" is not working properly in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsoperationqueue

I have two `NSOperation` objects "A" and "B", and want to use dependency as I need to let complete "B" first and then start "A".

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSOperationQueue *myQueue = [NSOperationQueue new];
    NSOperation *op1 = [[NSOperation alloc] init]; // Its a background(concurrent) thread.
    op1.completionBlock =^{
        NSLog(@"A");  
    };

    NSOperation *op2 = [[NSOperation alloc] init];  
    op2.completionBlock =^{

        NSLog(@"B");
    };
    [op1 addDependency:op2];
    [myQueue addOperation:op1];
    [myQueue addOperation:op2];
}
```

Expected Output:

```
 B
 A
```

But sometimes:

```
 A
 B
```

But I want to complete first B and then need to start A. Please help me on it.

Comment: Can you show how this code is called?  Is it called successively, like in a loop?

Comment: @danh, not in loop. I just placed in "viewDidLoad" method.

Comment: I see.  That blows my theory.   Do you have a way to reliably reproduce the out of order behavior?  Just for fun, can you add `[myQueue waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished];`

Comment: Check my ans if suits ..

Comment: Check this block you get clear idea https://www.appcoda.com/ios-concurrency/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could able to achieve it by using `NSBlockOperation`class instead of `NSOperation`. Here is a sample code snippet.

```
    NSOperationQueue *myQueue = [NSOperationQueue new];
    NSBlockOperation *blockOp1 = [[NSBlockOperation alloc] init];
    [blockOp1 addExecutionBlock:^{

        NSLog(@"1");
    }];

    NSBlockOperation *blockOp2 = [[NSBlockOperation alloc] init];
    [blockOp2 addExecutionBlock:^{

    NSLog(@"2");
    }];

    [blockOp1 addDependency:blockOp2];
    [myQueue addOperation:blockOp1];
    [myQueue addOperation:blockOp2];

   Output: 2
           1
```

Answer (score 1):

1. First Create Operation op1
2. If data provided by Operation op2 is not available, create Operation op2
3. make Operation op1 dependent on Operation op2. ie. something like `op1.addDependency(op2);`

or check this also

```
NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
NSOperation *op1;
NSOperation *op2;

//... initialize op1 and op2 however you please ...

[op1 setCompletionBlock:^{
        if ([op1 satisfiesSomeCriteria]) {
            [queue addOperation:op2];
        }
 }];
[queue addOperation:op1];
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. If we do like above then what is the use/purpose of "addDependency" method?

Answer (score 1):

Here completion blocks are not part of the queue instead they run outside of the Operation Queue on another thread. Thus Operation A's completionBlock will run at the same time as Operation B.

According to your ques you are using the completionBlocks to pass information from operation A to B.

Here are some solution:

- Give B references to all the A's (not weak) so when B runs it can pick the results from operation A.
- keep all the A operation around until B runs, then recreate your Completion Block's as another `NSOperation` see code below:

---

```
NSOperation *operA = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^{ // do stuff 
}]; 

NSOperation *operationATail = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^{ // do completionBlock stuff
}]; 

// First bullet point
[operationATail addDependency:operA];

// Second bullet point
[operationB addDependency:operationATail]; 

[self.queue addOperations:@[operA, operationATail, operationB] waitUntilFinished:NO];
```

Comment: I was able to get it by using "NSBlockOperation" but I wanted to do it through "NSOperation".  No need to add dependency again "[operationB addDependency:operationATail];".